# How to resolve the flicker issue in UIWebview?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I am using the UIWebview to display the html content. While loading the html content into UIWebview some flicker effect is appeared.

How to remove the flicker issue while loading Html content in UIWebview?

Answer (score 0):

Use the WKWebViewConfiguration to turn on `suppressesIncrementalRendering`.